# Does Apple have a method in iOS to securely provide the services from a public/private key pair to all instances of the same iOS app on 9.3 or later?

Tags: ios, security, cryptography, ios9

**What is a valid method to securely provide all instances of an app across different devices with a public/private key pair that would be used both to encrypt and decrypt data records created any of those devices, such that any instance of the app on any device can decrypt the records encrypted with those keys?**

In particular, this is for a cloud-based iOS app on 9.3 or later that stores extremely sensitive information in some proprietary cloud-based servers. We don't want our own cloud server having the private key however, to eliminate the possibility of the key being leaked should our main server get hacked.

I was hoping there'd be a way for example to have Apple inject a common key to the system keychain at app install, so that no human outside of Apple's security fortress itself could see the private keys, and it would be as secure as the device's system keychain.

---

**Existing options that I know about for storing a private key that would be accessed across all instances of the same app**:

(1) **Hard-code a key-pair right into the app.**
Downfall: If someone gets access to the code repository, and/or sufficiently decompiles the app, they can reconstruct the private key.

(2) **Have the device connect to iCloud via CloudKit and pull down the key-pair from the app's public container, then store it into the system keychain.** Downfall: an attacker who compromises the right AppleID credentials could gain access to everything needed to decrypt the data. Also, Apple's latest security white paper says an app's public iCloud container is "not encrypted".

(3) **Have the app require a configuration profile be installed that contains the certs.** Downfall: the source of the configuration profile could be owned by an attacker.

(4) **Combination of 1 through 3: assemble the private key at launch time from a bunch of bits and pieces that are hard-coded, come from iCloud, and come from some.** Downfall: less downfall by making an attacker jump over more hurdles is not *no downfall*.

(5) Is there a five?

---

**What I want ideally** is an Apple-provided way to inject a special key-pair into the system keychain of the device at the time of app install, such that that:

- the app itself has role in the key injection, which would be done prior to the app launching
- the app itself has no direct access to the key pair
- all the app can do is pass things to a system framework to handle signing/encrypting/decrypting operations that rely on these keys
- this key-pair is not available to versions of the app that are not signed by Apple (i.e. beta/dev/QA versions rely on proxy certs)
- all copies of the app the same results from the same key-pair
- the developer can reset the key-pair, at which point subsequent updates of the app can have the system do a one-time transition of data from being encrypted with the old key to being encrypted with the new one

... does Apple provide such a method? Or anyone else?

Comment: No, the problem is not to share the key between different apps on the same device. The problem is to share the key between the same app on different devices.

Comment: Why do you want a public/private key pair, asymmetric encryption is generally not used to encrypt data, it is really slow and the data size is limited to less than the key size. Data is generally encrypted with symetric key cryptography such as AES. This seems like a XY question where you have pre-decided a asymmetric encryption is part of the answer.

Comment: How it is decided which devices are part of the group that shares the documents?

Comment: Well frankly it doesn't necessarily have to be a keypair... but we want to use the public key to encrypt certain things from the server potentially, that would become non-readable by the server but all the apps could still read it. How it's decided which devices are part of the group that shares the documents is whether or not the device has the app installed.

Comment: No, the server does not give all the documents of all the users to all the users. It only gives them their own documents, and it encrypts them with the client-side-generated public key before sending. So an individual client can only ever get the records associated with the account the client is assigned to. However each client may have many iPads, each with their own public key; but all those iPads need to be able to encrypt certain data such that only the iPads (but not the server) can decrypt it. That's where this above question came into play.

Comment: What is a client, a single device or possibly several devices owned by one person. Let's say a user has two iPads, can they be associated so they can share documents and if so how are they associated. That was what I was asking with: "How it is decided which devices are part of the group that shares the documents".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

EDIT: More details on the method.

Step 1: Use OpenSSL to generate a set of keypairs, **K1** through **KN**, where **N** is the total number of layers of encryption on the data, with the following command:

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out NPrivateKey.pem 2048

openssl rsa -in NPrivateKey.pem -out NPrivateKeyOpen.pem -outform PEM

openssl rsa -in NPrivateKey.pem -pubout -out NPublicKey.pem -outform PEM
```

Step 2: Split up each key into a number **F** of separate files. These are the *fragments*.

Step 3: Encrypt each fragment of **KN** with **KN+1** (**K1** does not get encrypted).

Step 4: Create strategies **S1** through **SN** for shuffling the order of the fragments of **K1** through **KN** such that they can be algorithmically recombined into the original key by the app at runtime, assuming it knows **N** for a given **K** (how it knows **N** can be handled through an entirely separate process, if desired). This step allows for the fragments to exist in memory in a shuffled form for an additional degree of obscurity (for what it's worth). The goal here is simply to erect as many hurdles as possible in the path of a would-be attacker. For example if any aspects of the key were stored together on disk somewhere (for example in a repo or corporate key vault, etc.) this would tend to defeat simple attempts to scan a data volume, for example, using a regex sequence to identify keys stored on disk. If we are defeated, let it not be by a script kiddie—know what I'm saying?

Step 5: Create a strategy **D1** through **DN** for the distribution of the fragments such that the app can collect all the fragments at runtime.

Step 6: Should any fragments be stored in the app's code itself they should be stored using the strongest possible form of obscurity, e.g. a set of *purely* algorithmic function calls that can output the key but that store *no part* of the key as a string literal. The strategy used for this obscurity would be **O1** through **ON**, and which obscurity strategy is used for which fragment for which key is also shuffled according to strategy **OS**. (The use of method swizzling and dynamic runtime features of a language like Objective C can be useful here in creating some fun tricks to defeat anyone who gets a debugger attached to tell what the heck is going on; of course the distribution builds should always reject debugger connections, but that is out of scope for this answer.)

Step 7: All sections of the codebase implementing any aspects of the above strategies or storing any obscured key fragments should *never ever* appear in *any* commits to the primary code repository for the project. Git filters should be used in tandem with scripts (time for fun with Swift shells scripts!) to smudge and clean all such code. A completely separate repository should be maintained on an encrypted drive stored in a physical safe, that is only brought out when the relevant static library/objects need to be recompiled. That way even if someone gains access to the github account (or whatever) they will not gain access to the strategies or fragments.

Step 8: Do not store any keys in the system keychain. We have seen iOS's system keychain be compromised before. Other answers on StackOverflow can guide you on how to use a private key to decrypt data on iOS without the private key ever going into the system keychain. Perhaps this is a debatable point since the key could be deleted out of the keychain as soon as it's put in there, and for extra obscurity, you could do like we did and only store *some* of the keys in the stack in there, and store some of the encrypted fragments as if they were password hashes, etc. (all just more obscurity to lead people down false paths and confusing mazes that might try to break it).

Again, of course I have no doubt that it's technically *possible* to defeat this (or any) form of encryption; however the goal is simply to provide as steep of a hill to climb as is reasonably possible for a would-be attacker, yet ultimately have multiple clients be able to share the same private key.

Please refer to the article, [Secure Key Distribution Using Fragmentation and Assimilation in Wireless Sensor and Actor Networks](http://dsn.sagepub.com/content/11/9/542856.full), which I discovered after developing the above solution. Ghafoor et al.'s "KDFA" method is in many respects similar to what I have described above.

Also, please note that I'm sure anyone implementing such a solution as this will realize that there are many points in the process where additional layers of obscurity and encryption can (and should) be interjected; the goal of this answer is merely to describe the broad strokes of the method. The devil is in the details, and precisely *how* this method is implemented could make it more, or less secure.

Also, of course, I believe it goes without saying that all network-based communication involved in the distribution strategies must be secured with TLS 1.2 w/PFS (or whatever the new best thing is when ever you are reading this in the future). Of course, further individual-client-specific private keys should be used *on top of* the shared private key. Of course, all the normal best practices in every regard are observed.

However the issue of how to distribute the same key to a group of devices such that only the clients, but not the server, can decrypt the data, is the problem, even if we follow all the best practices. What we have seen time and time again is that no matter how secure clients are, if someone owns the server then the fox gets all the eggs in the hen house. However if the server is merely a storage facility for totally encrypted data and the client employs a sufficiently dynamic and complex method to encrypt/decrypt that data, then it tends to help the concern of "what if the server gets owned" and "what if the code repository gets owned" etc.

Now if there are any major flaws in the above approach then of course, I would love to hear that so it can be improved.

---

I just ended up taking two keypairs. One of them I used to encrypt the other one. Then I broke up the encrypted form into many shards and stashed them all over the place... in the cloud... on servers... in obfuscated strings on my app... etc.

None of the strings involved in the encryption or keys is in string or binary format in the compiled app. It is all generated programatically in a quite obfuscated fashion.

At runtime we use arcane math functions to build method names that call hidden methods around the app to assemble the first key, then we go get the encrypted shards of the second key from all over the internet and decrypt them with the first key, then we use the second key to decrypt the important client data.

Then we use a special sauce method where none of the code that's involved in this obfuscation is anywhere in our repository. It gets loaded in dynamically at a special time. :D That's all I will say about that.

Comment: So, you have given up on security and opted just for obscurity. OK, that is fine for a toy app where there are few users and they do not expect security. Of course the option is to have a cryptographic security domain expert design the system and review the code but that would cost money and it seems that the security you say you need and your users expect is not worth that. Yep, we software developers are not professionals, just code monkeys after all.

Comment: ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break.

Comment: Well, @zaph, I have already recommended to my bosses such a review by experts, but in the mean time we just needed to have *some* kind of encryption in place for certain types of data so it was not decryptable from the server. For the foreseeable future, only one user will be using this aspect of the platform, and before we add more users, we will have had said security review by specialists. Using two layers of AES-256, 2048-bit encryption is far more than any of our competition uses for the same type of data already. Anyway I'm open it if you have any substantive suggestions.

Comment: I'd also like to add that my estimation of the "solution" I put in place for the problem is that, like with all such attempts, of course it could be broken by the right person. However, the goal here was not to put in place an "unbreakable" form of encryption, but rather, to put enough hurdles in place that a would-be hacker would have some difficult rows to hoe. I'm under no delusion, as you suggest with your Schneier quotation, that the method of encryption used here is unbreakable. I'm sure one of the three-letter agencies would handle it, but we want to thwart average snoops.

Comment: Well, Zaph, your comments are very non-constructive. You have not said what specifically about my answer is bad, only indicated you think so. Well, that's honestly not the point of StackOverflow comments sections. They are not here simply so you can go around saying, "This answer is wrong" without saying why. Please justify your comments. Thank you.

Comment: Replacing my previous comment, here is the problem: Encryption security is obtained by a secure algorithm that is known and a key which s secret, not by a secret algorithm. See Security through obscurity. As an example of security not obscurity see iOS Security, 63 pages describing iOS security in detail. The point is the security is obtained by good practices well described, not obscurity.

Comment: Also see: Apple Blackhat 2016 "Behind the Scenes of iOS Security" [Slides](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-16/materials/us-16-Krstic.pdf) and [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLGFriOKz6U)

Comment: The "secret algorithm" is merely one of several obscurity layers involved in the overall method—and is not, by any means, the linchpin of the strategy. I'm not sure why you seem to have fixated purely on that one aspect of the answer, but I figure I just was not clear enough, so I have updated the answer with more details, since I realize I was quite vague in the initial answer. Perhaps if you review that updated version, and you still feel it is a cockamamy scheme, then you can refer to some specific detail where I went wrong. Thank you.

Comment: OMG, that is like a [Rube Goldberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine) machine, this is priceless! There is an axiom that the more complicated something is the more difficult to avoid errors. One error in the right place and all security is lost. If you really want to have real security hire a cryptographic domain expert at least to advise and vet the method and code, that is what I have done.

Comment: So you're criticizing an encryption/security scheme... for being complex? Wow. I hope you never actually read about how the encryption algorithms themselves work...!

Comment: Also, we have developed our implementation of this using test driven development the entire way, so honestly it was not hard to make it work. While yes, the code is not simple, it's really not that bad when you get right down to it. Because we did it in a modular fashion it's not at all like a Rube Goldberg machine; each module stands alone like a black box and takes input and output in a very predictable, testable, and verifiable fashion. Yeah, it would not work if it had a bug, but you could say the same thing for pretty much any computer software.

Comment: But obviously you don't have any direct criticism of the method described here. And as I already stated the company will be bringing people in for a full security audit but we needed to get something in place even during our development phases before main launch.

Comment: The issue with "the more complicated something is the more difficult to avoid errors" is not getting it to work but rather to be secure. TDD would be successful testing a Caesar Cipher or RC4 and totally miss the security weaknesses. If you look at the history of locking (in software) the method kept getting more complex after each failure to the point no one could see the flaws until it failed. Finally the underlying flaw was recognized and that the  test and set instruction is needed, they it became simple, clear, obvious and it worked.

Comment: @zaph Thank you for taking the time to do that. I appreciate that criticism of the method. The above method in my answer does allow that if **SN == 1**, **DN == 1**, and **ON == 3** in the various steps, then the method is far simpler. I agree it could get burdensomely complicated with very high values of **xN**. However, I can't see how it could possibly be *more secure* to sacrifice any of these steps; not obscuring the key, or keeping it in the main code repo, or distributing it from a centralized source, all make it easier for the key to get compromised.

Comment: The steps I listed are not merely there to add complexity, they're each there to address a specific point of weakness where a key could get compromised. Obscurity prevents someone from just scanning your binary for strings. Distribution of fragments prevents someone who gains access to one of the key stores from getting the entire key. Encrypting the distributed fragments might be the least valuable step, but I don't see how it can hurt to make sure no private key is ever stored in an unencrypted form. But I'd love to hear an *actual suggestion* for a better approach here...

Comment: You can do what ever you want, justify it ayway you want, good, bad or ugly.

Comment: Well, what I want to do is to add some security, and I have no particular attachment to the ideas that I already put forth. It was just the best I could come up with having posted a question here and received no answers, only someone saying my answer was bad, but not specifically why other than "it's compliacted" and "hire a professional" basically. Do you see any other answers on StackOverflow like that? "I don't know the answer but hire a real programmer"? It's not the point of this site to simply say, "You're wrong LOL". I guess maybe I'm on the wrong stackexchange for security questions.

Comment: If you break your arm, and you go to MO (Medical Overflow) and they tell you to get a doctor do you complain? Then do you come up with a self conjured fix for your broken bone and when told that it really is not a good plan do you complain again? Same thing as this question.

Comment: Some things, security is one, require expertise in the subject in order to get it correct. There are certifications that require a minimum of 5-years of full time supervised experience, substantial pre-test study, a 6-hour proxied test and 40 hours of yearly continuing education, CISSP is one. Expecting a quick how-to on SO may be to much to expect. In the past I have always hired a security expert to vet my design and review the code in order to insure the users are properly protected. It is all about the users.